# How to stream chunks of local files into client components in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, stream, buffer, fetch-api

I am trying to stream chunks of data from a local file to a client component in Next.js

In the client component, I am using `fetch` to call a GET request from a Next.JS route, which creates a readable stream and then returns the first chunk of data from the file.

Of course, this is not useful because it only returns the first chunk. **I want to know how to re-configure my code so that I can get subsequent chunks when the client component requests them from the route**

My desired flow is:

- Client: Click to start stream reading file
- Server Route: sends first chunk
- Client: requests second chunk
- Server Route: sends second chunk

.. and so on, until the chunk is empty or no more chunks.

I can share the example code for the `page.tsx`, the client component, and `route.ts` which creates the readable stream and returns the first chunk.

app/useStreamingData/page.tsx

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UseStreamingData = () => {
  const [currentChunk, setCurrentChunk] = useState<string>("");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentChunk !== "") {
      setNextChunk();
    }
  }, [currentChunk]);

  const setNextChunk = async () => {
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/stream-file");
    //this pattern always returns the first chunk from file's readable stream
    //how do I get the next chunk??
    let json = await response.json();
    setCurrentChunk(json.data);
  };

  return <div onClick={setNextChunk}>UseStreamingData</div>;
};

export default UseStreamingData;
```

app/stream-file/route.ts

```js
import { createReadStream } from "fs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const filepath = "path/to/app/bigFile.json";

export async function GET(): Promise<NextResponse<{ data: string; error: string }>> {
  let response = await resolveChunkPromise(filepath);
  return NextResponse.json(response);
}

function resolveChunkPromise(filepath: string): Promise<{ data: string; error: string }> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //create a readable stream of my local file
    const readstream = createReadStream(filepath, { highWaterMark: 16 }); //very small buffer partition even small files into multiple chunks
    readstream
      .on("data", (chunk) => {
        //this returns the first chunk, the remaining chunks are never sent to client side
        resolve({ data: chunk.toString(), error: "" });
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        reject({ data: "", error: err });
      });
  });
}
```

[image]

My ideal solution is some sort of hook, like [react-fetch-streams](https://github.com/rolandjitsu/react-fetch-streams). Unfortunately the documentation did not help me enough to use it correctly (again - I could only get the first chunk of data). There is also ["can-ndjson-stream"](https://canjs.com/doc/can-ndjson-stream.html), but again I couldn't get this to work and it seems like it is only useful for new-line-delimited json, not any file. All examples I find do not show the server side code, and they assume there is an external url for fetching data, not a local file.

Comment: It looks like 'react-fetch-streams' is only useful for creating / using a stream once the entire file is sent to front end. This isn't useful if the file array is too large to send in the first place.